# Read csv (comma separated file) with values in quotation marks and comma as a decimal point

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a file with data like this:

```
    2.10.2014 23:30:00,"25,1",nan,nan,nan
    2.10.2014 23:30:00,nan,"15,2",nan,nan
    2.10.2014 23:30:00,nan,nan,"125,14",nan
    2.10.2014 23:45:00,nan,0,nan,nan
```

I'd like read this file. The desired output:

```
    2.10.2014 23:30:00 25.1  nan   nan     nan
    2.10.2014 23:30:00 nan   15.2  nan     nan
    2.10.2014 23:30:00 nan   nan   125.14  nan
    2.10.2014 23:45:00 nan   0     nan     nan
```

It is important to notice that if value `0` occurs the quotation mark is gone.

For this moment my code looks like this:

```
     import pandas as pd
     import csv

     df=pd.read_csv("file.csv",
                    sep=',\s+',
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
                    header=None, 
                    encoding="mbcs")
```

results in:

```
     "2.10.2014 23:30:00,""25,1"",nan,nan,nan"
```

Instead of `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` I've also tried using `escapechar='"'`

Comment: Use a `for loop` to index each line and use another `for loop` nesting it to read the data in each column. use `lstrip('"')` and `rstrip('"')` function to strip off the quotes. then read. It'll work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pass `decimal=','` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
In [28]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""2.10.2014 23:30:00,"25,1",nan,nan,nan
    2.10.2014 23:30:00,nan,"15,2",nan,nan
    2.10.2014 23:30:00,nan,nan,"125,14",nan
    2.10.2014 23:45:00,nan,0,nan,nan"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), decimal=',', header=None)

Out[28]:
                        0     1     2       3   4
0      2.10.2014 23:30:00  25.1   NaN     NaN NaN
1      2.10.2014 23:30:00   NaN  15.2     NaN NaN
2      2.10.2014 23:30:00   NaN   NaN  125.14 NaN
3      2.10.2014 23:45:00   NaN   0.0     NaN NaN
```

Additionally you can pass `parse_dates=[0]` to interpret the first column as `datetime`:

```
In [31]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), decimal=',', header=None, parse_dates=[0])

Out[31]:
                    0     1     2       3   4
0 2014-02-10 23:30:00  25.1   NaN     NaN NaN
1 2014-02-10 23:30:00   NaN  15.2     NaN NaN
2 2014-02-10 23:30:00   NaN   NaN  125.14 NaN
3 2014-02-10 23:45:00   NaN   0.0     NaN NaN
```

In your case ignore the `io.StringIO` bit, this is just for me to load your data from a text string just do:

```
df=pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=',\s+', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, header=None, decimal=',', parse_dates=[0], encoding="mbcs")
```

Comment: how to load file in `io.StringIO` ?

Comment: Ignore this, in your case just do `df=pd.read_csv("file.csv",
                    sep=',\s+',
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
                    header=None, decimal=',', parse_dates=[0],
                    encoding="mbcs")`

Comment: I got `ValueError: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators, but this causes 'decimal' to be ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine.`

Comment: If your csv is formatted like you state you don't need the `sep` param, try: `df=pd.read_csv("file.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, header=None, decimal=',', parse_dates=[0], encoding="mbcs")` as the default `sep` param is comma anyway

Comment: Unfortunately this creates `"2.10.2014 23:30:00 ""25 1"" NaN NaN nan"` and value 25 and 1 are in separate columns

Comment: What about `pd.read_csv("file.csv", decimal=',', header=None, parse_dates=[0])`?

Comment: `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 5` example data can be found here   http://dpaste.com/1NSVDPD

Comment: This imports fine for me using my code, what version pandas, python are you using? I'm using pandas 0.16.2 and python 3.3.4 64-bit

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.16.2 and python 3.4.3 64-bit

Comment: I think it's best you post a download link to the raw file, at the moment I can't reproduce your error at all, for instance if you ran my code does it work for you as is, I'm not talking about loading your csv but copying my code and running it

Comment: You were right. Your code works. I wanted to have very small file so I've deleted data using Ms Excel and saved as csv. I've also copied data from `dpaste.com` directly to Excel to check it. Using Notepad ++ solved ma problem. Thank you !